# Should I take the GRE physics subject test for a chemistry PhD?

Tags: graduate-admissions, physics, gre, chemistry

I plan on applying to top chemistry graduate programs (MIT, Caltech etc.)

I took the Chemistry subject test, score isn't in yet but I think  it's with high expected value (because I knew everything) but also high variance (because I worked...sub-optimally...and maybe made a ton of stupid mistakes) so it's a bit iffy.

I also noticed that I can answer most (~80%) of the questions on the Physics subject test and decided to sign up for that one too. It won't be a high score - I obviously can't compete with physicists - but just want to showcase my decent physics background (deeper than most chemists).

Is it in any way beneficial to send chemistry graduate programs also a mediocre physics score? Should I give it up and try to retake the chemistry test?